# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ttps://registry.npmjs'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am running `npm install` and I am getting this error:

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ttps://registry.npmjs'

I have tried running `npm cache clean --force` and rerunning `npm install` but that does not work either.

Comment: Hi! could you provide a little bit more context? is there a `package.json` file in the folder where you are running the command? if so, what does it contain ?

Comment: I'd check both your package.json and your .npmrc files for weird things.  Is there a longer error message?